# Manipulating margins between some of the plots in a grid of plots

Tags: r, plot, layout

I am using `layout` to stack my 12 plots into one plot, but would like to manipulate, or rather remove, the margins between certain plots.

This script:

```
layout.matrix <- matrix(c(1,2,7,8,3,4,9,10,5,6,11,12),nrow=4,ncol=3)
layout(layout.matrix,
       heights=c(1,2,1,2),
       widths=c(2,2,2),respect=F)
layout.show(12)
```

results in this layout:

[image]

I have been playing around with `par` as well, but can't find a solution to my problem, which is that I in this grid of plots need to remove the margin between plots 1 and 2, between 3 and 4, between 5 and 6, between 7 and 8, between 9 and 10, and between 11 and 12.

Suggestions?

Comment: Don't you define `par(mar=.)` repeatedly for each plot? I can't see the problem.

Comment: That was it, even though setting bottom and top margins to zero for plots next to each other still leaves a little magrin. Thanks.